# Alt Code in MS Word - different code but same character

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, alt-code

Why does using those two Alt codes in MS Word produce the same character?

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>

This character: `Ž`

But in any other programs I tried so far (even MS Excel) the character `}` gets produced when using this Alt code:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> produces the character `Ž` because 142 corresponds to this character in the [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) code page.

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> also produces the character `Ž`, because 381 is the decimal value of U+017D which correponds to this character in Unicode.

Alt codes <s>with 4 digits</s> *starting with 0* produce the corresponding characters in the *ANSI code page ([Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), by default)*.

Alt codes <s>with up to 3 digits</s> *not starting with 0* produce the corresponding characters in the *OEM code page ([Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), by default)*.

All code pages have only 256 characters (0 to 255), so any alt code larger than 255 would produce the corresponding Unicode character in Word.

However, this does not apply to Excel, which simply computes the modulo 256 value and produces that character (<s>in code page 437 or 1252, depending if it has 3 or 4 digits</s> *in OEM or ANSI code page, depending on the first digit*). Note that 381-256=125, which corresponds to `}` (in ASCII <s>therefore in all code pages</s>).

Comment: There's some wrong info. 1) Code page can be changed, not fixed at 1252 and 437. 2) The selected code page doesn't depend on the *length* but the first digit. Try `Alt+07` and see the bell in CP1252 rings instead of printing `•` in CP437 despite the length isn't 4, and not even 3. 3) The decimal behavior for values larger than 255 is specific to Word. Most other apps including Excel and PowerPoint use the default Windows behavior where the value are always modulo 256. 4) Not all code pages have the lower 128 code points the same as ASCII, so `therefore in all code pages` is wrong

Comment: Indeed, I have made some corrections in the answer, based on your comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The result of an Alt-code combination depends on both the *foreground application* and the *first numpad key*

---

Many applications have special treatment for Alt-code when they're in the foreground and receiving input. For example some apps simply take the first 3 digits and throw away the others. **MS Word also captures the whole digit sequence but treats the whole decimal value as the Unicode code point** without modulo. Wordpad also does the same. That's why <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0381</kbd> works in Word but not in most other apps. You don't even need the `0` prefix, just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>381</kbd> is enough

Word, Wordpad and other similar text editors like Libre Office also have an alternative which is typing the Unicode hexadecimal code point then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, so try typing `17D` or `U+17D` then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

---

However most other applications don't capture the Alt-code and use the ***default Windows behavior*** instead, in which the decimal values are always **modulo 256** (i.e. only the least significant byte is taken), and when holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> the first numpad key defines the type of code page to use:

- If it's <kbd>numpad 1-9</kbd> then the [DOS code page (A.K.A OEM code page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#MS-DOS_code_pages) will be used

  The default OEM code page on US Windows is [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set), so if you type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>144</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>400</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>656</kbd>... for example, then code point 144 in CP437 (which is U+00C9 `É` if you check the CP437 table in the previous link) will be typed in, because *656 mod 256 = 400 mod 256 = 144*
- If it's <kbd>numpad 0</kbd> then the [Windows code page (A.K.A ANSI code page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#ANSI_code_page) will be used

  By default the Windows code page is [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout) on US Windows. So if you type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0201</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0457</kbd>... then code point 201 in CP1252 will be typed in, which is also the same U+00C9 `É`

  Similarly <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0142</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0398</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0654</kbd>... all produce U+017D character `Ž` which is code point 142 in CP1252, because *654 mode 256 = 398 mod 256 = 142*

  In the same vein <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0381</kbd> produces code point 381 mod 256 = 125 which is `{`

  As a matter of fact Alt code originates from the DOS era, and people are so used to the Alt code in DOS that Microsoft can't break it when they use ANSI code pages in Windows and must differentiate the two with the `0` prefix
- If it's <kbd>numpad +</kbd> then input is hexadecimal [UCS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2)

  Typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> gives you the same `Ž` character

  Note that this requires the [hexnumpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code#Transition_to_Unicode) to be enabled by setting a `REG_SZ` value with name `EnableHexNumpad` in the `HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method` registry key then reboot

See also

- [Which character encoding is used for ALT-codes?](https://superuser.com/q/348674/241386)
- [PowerPoint: Alt+Unicode number results in replacement character](https://superuser.com/q/1497796/241386)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Word is interpreting ALT+0381 as Unicode U+017D, which is decimal representation 381

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters shows:

```
U+017D  Ž   381     &Zcaron;    Latin Capital Letter Z with caron   0317
```

You get the same result by entering the Unicode character normally. First type:

```
017D
```

Then press Alt+x

Any character you can find on https://www.alt-codes.net/ is the same in Word and Notepad++. I don' think there IS an ASCII character 0381, I'm not sure why other programs interpret it as `}`. The correct code would be alt+125 . Perhaps a smarter superuser can assist with that.

Comment: Some programs probably just do a mod 256 operation on a number that's supposed to be "ASCII" - if so, decimal 381 will come out as "}". Since there's no universal standard for how alt-keystrokes should work, I doubt you need an "explanation" beyond that.